# Return the list of files from Groovy's eachFile() in reverse order

Tags: groovy

I'm using [eachFile()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFile%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), but I'm trying to reverse the order that the iteration happens. How do I do that? Right now, it appears to sort the list of files and then process each one in sorted order. I essentially want to reserve-sort that list and start from the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can't alter the order of `eachFile()`, but you can achieve the desired effect.

Consider:

```
new File("desired dir").listFiles().sort{ it.name }.reverse().each { def f ->
    println f.name
}
```

Comment: `println f.class` would print `java.io.File` for all the files. :). Suggesting an edit, `println f.name`?

Comment: Note: `listFiles()` [does **not** guarantee](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) the order of the files!  If you want to guarantee the order, you need to insert `.sort()` before the reverse.  (Or just sort using a closure that is reversed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't using `eachFile` directly, but it's very simple to perform this using `listFiles` and a manual sort:

```
new File(path_to_file).listFiles().sort{a,b -> b.name <=> a.name}.each{ File f ->
    println f.name
}
```

The key here being the `sort{}` that is inverted.  (If you just use `reverse()` on `listFiles()`, you are not guaranteed any specific order from the file system — the files may come in a system-specific order.)

Note that that sort is case-*sensitive* — you can do a case-*unsensitive* sort like this:

```
new File(path_to_file).listFiles().sort{a,b -> b.name.compareToIgnoreCase(a.name)}.each{ File f ->
    println f.name
}
```

Tested under Groovy 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know is

```
def allFiles = new File('desired directory').listFiles()?.sort{a, b ->
    -(a.name <=> b.name)
}
```

`eachFile` cannot use `sort` in the closure.

The benefit of using `sort` explicitly is that you can sort the files according to your sort criteris. For example, sort files based on file's `lastModified` date:-

```
def allFiles = new File('desired directory').listFiles()?.sort{a, b ->
        a.lastModified() <=> b.lastModified()
        //to reverse sort on lastModified date use below
        //-(a.lastModified() <=> b.lastModified())
    }
```